# Within postgres query can I break a column into quartiles for partitioning results?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query that partitions data based on a specific column but I'm trying to now partition it based on quartiles within my dataset. So for example, say I have industry of "tech" and "retail" but I break it down in quartiles then for each industry there would be 4 additional partitions.

How can I incorporate it? Do I need to get the quartiles first then pass it into the below code? or can I directly partition the revenue column into quartiles within my partition by line?

```
with data as (
    select
        g.ticker,
        g.industry,
        g.countryname,
        g.exchange,
        c.year,
        c.revenue,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY g.industry ORDER BY c.revenue ASC) AS groupingNumRank,
        AVG(c.revenue) over (PARTITION BY g.industry) as industavg,
        ... and so on
```

I may want to try other ways of splitting the data(maybe in deciles, percentages, etc..), if that's possible as well I'd be interested in learning how to do it.

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: @eshirvana I am trying to make it simple, I can add the code but the script is fairly large right now. In a nutshell, I want to know if I can incorporate quartiles into the (PARTITION BY g.industry) line.

Comment: yes , you can , look up `ntile` function , but if you want us to help you with query , you need to provide sample data and desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would apparently want:

```
select ntile(4) over (partition by g.industry order by c.revenue) as quartile
```

Note that `ntile()` makes sure the tiles are as equal in size as possible.  This may result in two rows with the same revenue being in different tiles.

If you don't want this behavior, you can use `rank()` and arithmetic:

```
select ceiling( rank() over (partition by g.industry order by c.revenue) * 1.0 / 
                count(*) over (partition by g.industry)
              ) as quartile
```

Comment: Thank you so much Gordon. When I run above, and try to call it in my portion I get a error. I am doing - PARTITION BY g.industry, quartile.

I get - SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column "quartile" does not exist
  Position: 1224

Comment: @Lostsoul . . . I don't understand.  These are the expressions for defining quartile.  Just use whichever is more appropriate.

Comment: I may not be explaining it correct. When I refer to 'quartile' within the partition section of my query, I'm getting above error.

To clarify, I am right now partitioning basic on catergorial values(industry, country, etc) but I want to also partition based on numeric values so I was looking to create quartiles for each row & partition them accordingly in the averages, etc subqueries I created.

Comment: So in plain terms, right now I can partition companies by industry to get the average of a industry or the companies relative position. But what if I want the partition broken down further by quartiles. For example, for each industry, break companies into 4 groups based on revenue. so in this case for each industry I would have max 4 further partitions(Num of industry * 4 qurtiles).

Comment: @Lostsoul . . . Your question is about *defining* the quartiles.  If you want to use the quartile, you'll need a subquery or CTE.

Comment: sorry about that. I didn't know how to ask it. Basically, do I create a subquery within my partition statement above?